# Delete certain content from file

Tags: perl

How can I open a file in Perl, and delete certain things?
At the moment I am trying to delete phone numbers and email's.

I don't know where to start, apart from the file opening, so I haven't shared any code.

Comment: Here's a hint: read the entire file into memory (assuming it's small enough), and write it out again, ignoring the content you don't want included in the final file.

Comment: Files can go up to 1gb, and would I re-write it, and use regex?

Comment: If the files are that large, you might exhaust main memory if you read the entire file in at once. Instead, read them in line by line, or section by section. Yes, regex could work well for your application.

Comment: I don't see how this is "not a real question".

Answer (score 2):

You can't easily delete just parts of a file and then rewrite the file. Usually, you have to rewrite the file from scratch.

A simple Perl program like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $file_name = $ARG[0];

# Open file for reading and new for writing

open (my $read_fh, "<", $file_name);
open (my $write_fh, ">" "$file_name.temp");


# Read in line at a time, modify it, and write it

while (my $line = <$read_fh>) {

   # Modify the line some how to remove what you don't want

   $line =~ s/foo/bar/;

   print $write_fh $line;
}

close $read_fh;
close $write_fh;

# Delete the old file you read in and rename the new one

unlink $file_name;
rename "$file_name.temp" $file_name;
```

There are other ways (Use the `<>` operator, open file for reading and writing and use `seek`, read file into a list at once, use `map`) but in the end, it's pretty much this: You read in the file, modify the lines, and write them to a new file.

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on the format of the file.  Most Unix filesystems don't provide the ability to delete information in the middle of a file (I say most, but I don't know of a single one that does).  Your best bet is not to use a flat file.  A database of some form is what is called for if you need to do things like this.  There are many different types of databases out there and I am certain one will do what you want.

The simplest database available that seems to fit your needs (at least the ability to add and delete records) is [DBM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dbm).  In Perl 5, you can easily [tie a DBM file](http://perldoc.perl.org/AnyDBM_File.html) to a hash variable providing a fast, simple, transparent way of interacting with the database.

Of course, you could also use a relational database.  Relational databases are nice because they make it easy to ask all sorts of questions about the data you are storing and act on those queries.  A simple way to get started is with the [DBD::Sqlite](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-SQLite/lib/DBD/SQLite.pm) module (you will also need the [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm) module).  It is simple because the DBD::Sqlite module contains the entire database engine (which in most databases is a separate and occasionally expensive server).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a text file, I would recommend you [Tie::File](http://p3rl.org/Tie%3a%3aFile).  From the description:

> Tie::File represents a regular text file as a Perl array. Each element in the array corresponds to a record in the file. The first line of the file is element 0 of the array; the second line is element 1, and so on.

You can iterate through the array looking for the strings you want to, edit and your file will have the expected changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this on unix:

```
cat file| perl -ne 'print unless (/IGNORE_PATTERN/)' >new_file
```